# Foreign Key without ugly blablaId

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to do foreign key without blablaId?
I mean next situation

```
public class Blog 
{ 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
} 

public class Post 
{ 
    public int PostId { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; } 

    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Why should I have this ugly property? 
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; } 
}
```

My models are core project. But I should play EF rules. It means core project depend on DAL project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required declare the FK property in your entity. If you delete it, EF will create it for you in your DB.

However, imagine if the `Blog` is not in memory, this would require you to first execute a query on the database to retrieve that `Blog` so that you can set the property. There are times when you may not have the object in memory, but you do have access to that object’s key value. With a foreign key property, you can simply use the key value without depending on having that instance in memory:

```
currentPost.BlogId=2;
```

Comment: Yeap, but can we use laze load for Blog?

Comment: Yes, you can if you have not disable lazy loading in your context, it is enabled by default. Declaring or not the FK property does not affect lazy loading. In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) you will find the requirements you must follow if you want that your navigation properties be lazy loaded